# SVG arrows created from react-xarrows are not being converted into PDF format

Tags: svg, pdf-generation, xarrows

I have a page that renders cards for events from a database and then connects them using react-xarrows.  After the user is done creating their tree, i am trying to export the finished image a PDF to use in a report.  Everything but the arrows created by react-xarrows are converting to the PDF.

Screen shot the app running: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OCNT.png)

Below is what the PDF looks like:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmPME.png)

My code is below:

```
  let pdf = new jsPDF();
  let pdfExport = document.getElementById("pdf-export");
  html2canvas(pdfExport, { allowTaint: true }).then(function (canvas) {
    //convert to an image data URL
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    //add to pdf
    pdf.addImage(imgData, "PNG", 100, 100);
    pdf.save(`${selOutcome.outcomeTitle}.pdf`);
  });`
```

i have also tried converting the svg into a png and no luck.  i have entered the below svg string into many online generators and they generate the correct image, but i have been unable to get the arrows to appear in a pdf.  Below is the SVG string for one of the arrows:

```
<svg width="102.328125" height="67" overflow="auto" style="position: absolute; left: -1132.49px; top: 101.5px; pointer-events: none;" id="SVG66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M 86.328125 16 L  54.1640625 16 L 54.1640625 51 22 51" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="0 0" stroke-width="2" fill="transparent" pointer-events="visibleStroke" id="arrow66" style="opacity: 1;"></path><g fill="black" pointer-events="auto" transform="translate(24,55) rotate(180) scale(8)" opacity="1" id="arrowhead66" style="opacity: 1;"><animate dur="0.4" attributeName="opacity" from="0" to="1" begin="indefinite" repeatCount="0" fill="freeze"></animate><path d="M 0 0 L 1 0.5 L 0 1 L 0.25 0.5 z"></path></g></svg>
```

Comment: KJ, where are you seeing the transparent on the SVG?  is it beacuse of the animate portion that i'll need to strip before PDF rendering?  For the left negative value, i believe it is because the SVG Container gets drawn by react Xarrows relative to a div that is created at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Any pointers you have for how i can get this to render correctly on the screen would be appreciated.  I've also tried using a PNG converter and SVG to Canvas, but when i do a replace child. the placement is blank / transparent.

Comment: I have also worked with changing the properties of the SVG container, and can get the container itself to go to PDF by changing the container color to blue or green etc.., but still can't get the arrow to appear.